# ElasticSearch Painless: using vector functions in for loops bug

Tags: elasticsearch, vector, elasticsearch-painless

I ran into what seems to be a bug in Painless where if a vector function is used, say l2norm(), the outcome remains the same outcome as the first iteration. I'm using the painless script in a function score, I hope the query below sheds some light. I'm using the "exception" to see what the value is in each of the iteration, and it's every time the score of the first vector. I know this because I cycled the parameters a couple of times, and the score is everytime "stuck" on the first thing. So what I think is happening is that the function l2norm() (and all vector functions?!) are object instances that can only be instantiated one time? If that would be the case, what would be a work around?

Link to the ES discussion: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/painless-bug-using-for-loops-and-vector-functions/267263

```
    {
        "query": {
                "nested": {
                        "path": "media",
                        "query": {
                                "function_score": {
                                        "boost_mode": "replace",
                                        "query": {
                                                "bool": {                                                       
                                                        "filter": [{
                                                                "exists": {
                                                                        "field": "media.full_body_dense_vector"
                                                                }
                                                        }]
                                                }
                                        },
                                        "functions": [{
                                                "script_score": {
                                                        "script": {
                                                                "source": "if (params.filterVectors.size() > 0 && params.filterCutOffScore >= 0) {\n  for (int i=0; i < params.filterVectors.size();i++) {\n    def c = params.filterVectors[i];  double euDistance =  l2norm(c, doc['media.full_body_dense_vector']);\n  if (i==1) { throw new Exception(euDistance + ''); }        \n      }\n     return 1.0f;",
                                                                "params": {
                                                                      "filterVectors":[
[1.0,2.0,3.0],[0.1,0.4,0.5]
                                                                        ],
                                                                        "filterCutOffScore": 1.04
                                                                },
                                                                "lang": "painless"
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        }]
                                }
                        }
                }
        },
        "size": 500,
        "from": 0,
        "track_scores": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, thanks to Joe for confirming I wasn't imagining things and it's indeed a bug. Second, the lovely ElasticSearch team has been triaging the issue and confirmed it's a bug, so the answer to this post is [a link to the Github Issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/70437) so in the future, people can track in which ElasticSearch version this behaviour is patched.

Comment: Glad to confirm it  Hey Jan, shameless plug — do check my [Handbook](https://elasticsearchbook.com/) containing a chapter or two on some pretty advanced scripting use cases which might be helpful to ya!

Answer (score 1):

While `l2norm` is a [static method](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-api-reference-score.html#_static_methods_2), it certainly shouldn't behave like a pure function!

I've investigated a bit and it seems there's only a loop-level bug. When you call `l2norm` outside of the loop with either parametrized or hard-coded vectors, the results will always be different -- as they should be. But not within the for loop (I've tested a `while` loop too -- same result). Here's a minimum reproducible example that could be used to [report a bug on github](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/new/choose):

```json
"script": {
  "source": """
      def field = doc['media.full_body_dense_vector'];
      
      def hardcodedVectors = [ [1,2,3], [0.1,0.4,0.5] ];
      
      def noLoopDistances = [
        l2norm(hardcodedVectors[0], field),
        l2norm(hardcodedVectors[1], field)
      ];
      
      def hardcodedDistances = [];
      for (vector in hardcodedVectors) {
        double euDistance = l2norm(vector, field);
        hardcodedDistances.add(euDistance);
      }
      
      def parametrizedDistances = [];
      for (vector in params.filterVectors) {
        double euDistance = l2norm(vector, field);
        parametrizedDistances.add(euDistance);
      }
      
      def comparisonMap = [
        "no-loop": noLoopDistances,
        "hardcoded": hardcodedDistances,
        "parametrized": parametrizedDistances
      ];
      
      Debug.explain(comparisonMap);
     """,
  "params": {
    "filterVectors": [ [1,2,3], [0.1,0.4,0.5] ]
  },
  "lang": "painless"
}
```

which yields

```json
{
  "no-loop":[             
    8.558621384311845,    // <-- the only time two different l2norm calls behave correctly
    11.071133967619906
  ],
  "parametrized":[
    8.558621384311845,
    8.558621384311845
  ],
  "hardcoded":[
    8.558621384311845,
    8.558621384311845
  ]
}
```

What this tells me is that it's not a matter of [runtime caching](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html#_script_parameters) but rather something else that should be investigated further be the Elastic team.

The **workaround**, for now, would be to keep using the parametrized vectors but instead of looping **perform stone-age-like checks**:

```java
if (params.filterVectors.length == 0) {
  // default to something
} else if (params.filterVectors.length == 1) {
  // call l2norm once
} else if (params.filterVectors.length == 2) {
  // call l2norm twice, separately
}
```

---

P.S. Throwing a `new Exception()` in order to debug Painless is fine. Using `Debug.explain` is even better for reasons explained in [this sub-chapter on Debugging](https://elasticsearchbook.com/learn-elasticsearch/script-fields-debugging-bae4929eeaad414986d26f0b58187d66) of my [Elasticsearch Handbook](http://elasticsearchbook.com/).

Comment: Thanks so much Joe! I was really turning every rock to make sure I wasn't imagining an issue, I've already created a bug ticket, alongside with a ticket to allow null values for dense_vector fields, right now you have to script the removal because you cannot assign an empty array or "null". Link: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/70437

Comment: I've noticed your book, does it include function scoring that takes into account multiple blocks (i.e. vector score, terms matching, text query pushing out 1 score?) To get back to the question, it's really stupid, but since this is likely a bug I have no other option, my array of vectors is variable, so i just print them all out as if the for loop would run through them... horrible code...but it works and there's no other option :). Your if/else would work, but the length varies.

Comment: Nice, I've upvoted that GH issue of yours! The book does include plenty of material with regards to scoring, terms filtering, constant scores (1) etc, but, honestly, nothing on vectors. It's a broad take on multiple topics, all of which are listed on the homepage. Give it a shot!